# Visual Studio 16.3.10: Cant see properties of an object

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, local-variables

I'm currently writing some tests and the assertions fail. When I try to resolve the problem by exploring the object, the properties seems to be empty. Number of displayed rows is the same as the amount of defined properties in the class. What could cause such a weird problem? I already deleted all bin and obj folders and tried to clean rebuild.

[image: screenshot of quickwatch]

Edit: when I run `_tilefilter.getType().getMembers()` before inspecting the `_tilefilter` variable everything works as expected!

i see this as an workaround, but this is not how i want to use my debugger

Comment: Looks like you re using variables starting with underscore? All varibles with single or double underscore are reserved for language implementation. You should not use those.

Comment: I tried to rename the variable without the underscore, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Althought this still looks strange even for release build. Silly question, do you debug in debug build?

Comment: Hi, yes i use a debug build to debug

Answer (score 0):

> What could cause such a weird problem? I already deleted all bin and
>   obj folders and tried to clean rebuild.

**Test**

I created a new project which containing a Class called **_TestClass**. After that, I defined some member variables,constructors and member methods. At the same time, I created an instance of the class on the main output console and debugged it through a breakpoint, then monitored the instance through **QuickWatch**, and the result was to output the full member variables of the class without the same issue you had.

Besides, I guess `_tilefilter` is just an instance of a class which includes some accessible variables and methods in your side.

[image]

**My environment**: Visual Studio Community 16.3.10   Windows 10 Enterprise 1903

> when i run _tilefilter.getType().getMembers() before inspecting the
>   _tilefilter variable everything works as expected

[getType().getMembers()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmembers?view=netframework-4.8) function will captures the common members of all types in the class, not just the members of the class itself and the properties, methods, and so on in the default class. Anyway, when you use it, it will always list the array.

**Conclusion**

So, l think this issue could be more related to VS environment, settings, third party packages or the project itself. To troubleshoot your issue, you can try my suggestions below:

**Suggestions**

1. start your VS with [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) and then open your project to test again. This mode will exclude other third-party packages, plugins, load only, pure, default environment and services.
2. try to create a new project with the same file and test it.

`>` If it does not appear in the new project, it could be an issue in your initial project, please close VS Instance, delete .vs hidden folder(locate at the path of the solution), reopen your project and try again.

`>` If it also occurs in the new project, please try to [do a repair in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).Also, try to close all third-party software on the desktop.

**In addition**, if the steps do not work, please share the class and the codes to instantiate it. Hope it could help you.